# How to allow user to type in value in dropdown

Tags: asp.net

Forgive me if this is a stupid question but I can't find an answer.

I have an ASP.net web application with a DropDown list with static items in the DropDown. How do I make it so the user can either click the dropdown and select a value OR allow the user to type in a value that is not in the dropdown list?

Thank you

Comment: I assume you're using Web Forms not MVC. There's no simple answer. While HTML5 does introduce combobox-like behavior with `<datalist>`, ASP.NET WebForms does not support it, also most desktop browsers do not support it either. The best approach for now (late-2014) is to use a framework like jQuery UI which provides such UI components.